# the symplectic Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have a question about the symplectic Lie Algebra.
The symplectic Lie algebra is defined as follows.

We define a skew symmetrical matrix: $S:=$
$\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & I_n \\
-I_n & 0\\
\end{array}\right) $.

Then the symplectic Lie algebra is the set $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}:=\{A \in \mathbb{K}^{2n,2n} \mid A^TS=-SA\}$

Can one say that the symplectic Lie algebra consists of alls skew symmetrical matrices A which commute with S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0\\
0 & -B^T\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
A^T S = \begin{pmatrix}
B^T & 0\\
0 & -B\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I\\
-I & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0&B^T\\
B&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
SA= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I\\
-I & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0\\
0 & -B^T\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
0&-B^T\\
-B&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So this $A$ is in the Lie algebra for all $B$. $A$ is not necessarily skew symmetric in this case because $B$ can be anything that is n by n.

Skew symmetric matrices that commute with $S$ form part of the Lie algebra, but there is more.

Comment: Generalising this, the Lie algebra actually consists exactly of all matrices $\pmatrix{B&C\\D&-B^T}$ where $B,C,D$ are $n\times n$-matrices, and $C$ and $D$ are symmetric, while (as you note) there's no restriction on $B$. Accordingly, its dimension is $2n^2+n$.